# Implications of $\mathsf{P}\neq\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model

Tags: p-vs-np, machine-models

What are implications of $\mathsf{P}\neq\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model to $\mathsf{Turing}$ model and $\mathsf{Valiant's}$ counting complexity model?

In opposite direction what are implications of $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{BSS}$ model to $\mathsf{Turing}$ model and $\mathsf{Valiant's}$ counting complexity model?

Comment: I think this has been asked before. Have tried searching for it?

Comment: I got $VNP$ versus $VP$ implication in search not this.

Comment: AFAIK, the Boolean part of $P_{\mathbb{R}}$ lies in the counting hierarchy (by reduction to PosSLP) and $NP_{\mathbb{R}}$ is contained in PSPACE (See "On the complexity of numerical analysis" by Allender, Burgisser, Pedersen and Miltersen). So this should imply a separation between P and PSPACE?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\Ptime{\mathsf P} \newcommand\NP{\mathsf{NP}} \newcommand\poly{\mathsf{poly}}$
It is known that $\Ptime/\poly \neq \NP/\poly \implies \Ptime_{\mathbb C}\neq \NP_\mathbb{C}$ [1] where the latter two represent the classes $\Ptime$ and $\NP$ in the BSS model over the complex numbers. (You can take the contrapositive to obtain a consequence of $\Ptime_\mathbb C = \NP_\mathbb C$.) 
To the best of my knowledge, this is the only known result, though results of the same kind are known for other classes (in particular in *Koiran's weak model*).

For more on this, look at Chapter 1 (in particular Fig. 1.1) and Chapter 8 of Bürgisser's book [2].

[1] F. Cucker, M. Karpinski, P. Koiran, T. Lickteig, and K. Werther. On real
Turing machines that toss coins. In *Proc. 27th ACM STOC*, Las Vegas,
pages 335–342, 1995.
[2] Peter Bürgisser. *[Completeness and reductions in algebraic complexity theory](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/algebra/work/habil.pdf)*, 1998.

Comment: where in $[1]$ does it say $\mathsf{P/Poly}\neq\mathsf{NP/poly}\implies \mathsf{P_{\Bbb C}}\neq\mathsf{NP_{\Bbb C}}$?

Comment: also does failure of $\tau$ conjecture imply $\mathsf{P_{\Bbb C}}\neq\mathsf{NP_{\Bbb C}}$? or does $\mathsf{P_{\Bbb C}}\neq\mathsf{NP_{\Bbb C}}\iff \mathsf{P_{\Bbb R}}\neq\mathsf{NP_{\Bbb R}}$ hold?